# Common Lisp - type checking two variables

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Hi I'm a beginner in Common Lisp. I want to check if  two variables are integers. If both n and m are integers I want to it to return `-` if it is negative, `0` if it is zero, `+` if it is positive and `NIL` if it is not an integer for both n and m. I figured out how to do this with one variable but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with two variables. Thanks.

This is the code that takes a numeric argument and returns `-` if it is negative, `0` if it is zero, `+` if it is positive and `NIL` if its not an integer:

```
(defun sign (n)
 (if(typep n 'integer)
    (cond ((< n 0) '-)
          ((= n 0) 0)
          ((> n 0) '+))))
```

The output for each case is:

```
CL-USER> (sign 3) 

+

CL-USER> (sign -3) 

-

CL-USER> (sign 0) 

0

CL-USER> (sign 3.3)

NIL
```

This is the code I have for checking two variables which I want it to check if n and m are integers and if n and m are positive, negative or a zero:

```
(defun sign (n m)
 (if (and (typep n 'integer) (typep m 'integer))
  (cond (and ((< n 0) '-) ((< m 0) '-))
        (and ((= n 0) 0) ((= m 0) 0))
        (and ((> n 0) '+) ((> m 0) '+)) ))))
```

Answer (score 6):

Remember basic Lisp syntax. Function calls and some basic expressions are written as

```
(operator argument-0 argument-1 ... argument-n)
```

Right?

open parenthesis, operator, argument-0 argument-1 ... argument-n, closing parenthesis.

Now if we have `(< n 0)` and `(< m 0)` how would an `AND` expressions look like?

```
(and (< n 0) (< m 0))
```

But you write:

```
and ((< n 0) '-) ((< m 0) '-)
```

You have these mistakes:

- no parentheses around the AND expression.
- extra parenthesis around the argument expressions.
- `'-` mixed into the argument expressions.

Now `COND` expects:

```
(COND (testa1 forma0 forma1 ... forman)
      (testb1 formb1 formb1 ... formbn)
      ...
      (testm1 formm0 formm1 ... formmn))
```

So instead of

```
(defun sign (n m)
  (if (and (typep n 'integer) (typep m 'integer))
      (cond (and ((< n 0) '-) ((< m 0) '-))
            (and ((= n 0)  0) ((= m 0)  0))
            (and ((> n 0) '+) ((> m 0) '+)))))
```

Btw, there was an extra parenthesis at the end.

We write:

```
(defun sign (n m)
  (if (and (typep n 'integer) (typep m 'integer))
      (cond ((and (< n 0) (< m 0)) '-)
            .... )))
```

It's also possible to use predicates like `integerp`, `minusp`, `zerop` and `plusp`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the already functioning and tested `sign` definition - which is typical for the way, lispers program. The first naive solution would be:

```
(defun sign-for-two (n m)
  (when (eql (sign n) (sign m)) 
    (sign n))

;; (if (condition) return-value NIL)
;; is equivalent to 
;; (when (condition) return-value)
```

Note, in common lisp it is important, 
which equality test you choose:

```
;; only symbols - for object identity        eq
;; symbols or numbers - for object identity  eql
;;   (in most tests the default)
;; eql for each component? also in lists     equal
;; equal not only lists but also
;; arrays (vectors, strings), structures, hash-tables
;; however case-insensitive in case of strings
;;                                           equalp
;; mathematical number equality              =
;; specifically characters                   char=
;; case-sensitive string equality            string=
```

In our case, eql is sufficient.

```
;; to avoid `(sign n)` to be evaluated twice,
;; you could store it using `let` 
;; and call from then on the stored value
;; (which is less costly).

(defun sign-for-two (n m)
  (let ((x (sign n)))
    (when (eql x (sign m))
      x)))
```

Or create an equality tester (default test function: `#'eql`)
which returns the equally tested value
and if not equal, `NIL`:

```
(defun equality-value (x y &key (test #'eql))
   (when (funcall test z y) z)))

;; and apply this general solution to our case:
(defun sign-for-two (n m)
   (equality-value (sign n) (sign m)))
```

and you can apply the `equality-value` function
in future for functions where you want to
return the value when tested as "equal"
and you can give the function via `:test` whatever equality
function other than `eql` is suitable for that case, like

```
(equality-value string1 string2 :test #'string=)
```

Comment: The `let` inside `equality-value` is not necessary, but more importantly, calling `test` should be done with funcall.

Comment: @coredump ah thank you - I always appeciate your answers and comments! - I corrected this (funcall) at console but forgot to correct it at text. And true, the let inside `equality-value` is superfluous - I will remove it. I was too much thinking in terms of previous code :D .

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the right approach and just got lost in the parentheses. Each of your `cond` cases looks like

```
(and ((< n 0) '-) ((< m 0) '-))
```

I think you meant

```
((and (< n 0) (< m 0)) '-)
```

and the same thing for the other two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Another compact way to write `sign` is to use the standard function [`signum`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_signum.htm#signum) which

> returns one of -1, 0, or 1 according to whether number is negative,
>   zero, or positive

The code could look like:

```
(defun sign (n)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  (when (integerp n)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    (case (signum n)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
      (-1 '-)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      (0   0)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
      (1  '+))))
```